# Can two questions cover identical ground without being duplicates?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

In my opinion, [memcpy() vs memmove()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415910/memcpy-vs-memmove) and [What is the difference between memmove and memcpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201319/what-is-the-difference-between-memmove-and-memcpy) both cover the exact the same question. Normally I'd flag one of these as duplicate of the other.

However, in this case, both questions did get answers that a very comparable in quality, the question is clear in both questions, so I really cannot decide which one to flag. So the question appeared: *should I be flagging one of these questions*?

Can two identical questions coexist without being marked as duplicate?

Comment: Questions that are identical should be marked as duplicates. If both have good quality answers, ask for merge. If you can't decide basing on quality, use age to decide. I can imagine different, non-duplicate questions that happen to be solved by similar means - then they don't need to be duplicates - but that's not the case here.